# How to use react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi i am building web page in react and i need to add onclick function to my button that have simpel if else statment that in the en will open main.js. But i dont understand how react router is working can someone helt?

App.js

```
import { useState } from "react"
import { BrowserRouter, Link, Routes, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Main from "./main.js";

export default function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [inpty, setFull] = useState("");
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (inpty.trim().length === 0) {
      alert("Please input your name to continue");
    } else {
      <Routes>
        <Link to={<Main/>}/>
      </Routes>
    }
  }
  return (
    <section className="grid grid-cols-1">
      <div className=" h-screen w-screen fixed bg-gradient-to-r from-violet-500 to-blue-500 bg-cover">
        <h1 className="text-center bg-black text-white">Hi! If you want to support me you can allways check out my <a href="https://www.buymeacoffee.com/HTNR" className="text-[#FFDD00]">"Buy me some coffe"</a>. Thank you!</h1>
        <h1 className="font-customFont1 text-white text-xl mt-3 ml-3 smallP:text-lg mP:text-2xl tP:text-2xl tL:text-2xl sL:text-3xl mL:text-3xl lP:text-3xl">ZenZone</h1>
        <div className="h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
          <div className="grid-cols-1 grid bg-neutral-500 w-[40%] h-[30%] text-center bg-opacity-25 absolute rounded-2xl smallP:w-[60%] smallP:h-[40%] mP:w-[50%] mP:h-[40%] tP:w-[40%] tP:h-[40%] tL:w-[40%] tL:h-[40%] sL:w-[30%] sL:h-[40%] mL:w-[25%] mL:h-[40%] lP:w-[25%] lP:h-[40%]">
            <h1 className="font-roboto text-[#F8F7F4] smallP:mt-7 smallP:text-lg smallP:font-bold mP:text-xl mP:font-bold mP:mt-5 tP:text-2xl tP:font-bold tP:mt-7 tL:text-3xl tL:font-bold tL:mt-6 sL:text-3xl sL:font-bold sL:mt-4 mL:text-3xl mL:font-bold mL:mt-4 lP:text-3xl lP:font-bold lP:mt-4">Feel home</h1>
            <h1 className="font-robot text-[#F8F7F4] smallP:mt-5 smallP:font-bold smallP:text-lg mP:text-xl mP:font-bold mP:mt-3 tP:text-xl tP:font-bold tL:text-2xl tL:font-bold tL:-mt-2 sL:text-2xl sL:font-bold sL:-mt-4 mL:text-2xl mL:font-bold mL:-mt-3 lP:text-2xl lP:font-bold lP:-mt-3">Let's start with your name</h1>
            <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
              <div className="relative">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  value={inpty}
                  onChange={e => setFull(e.target.value)}
                  placeholder="Carlos Hill"
                  className="border-b border-gray-300 py-1 focus:border-b-2 focus:border-blue-700 transition-colors focus:outline-none peer bg-inherit smallP:w-32 smallP:text-lg text-white smallP:mt-5 mP:w-44 mP:text-xl mP:mt-5 tP:w-52 tP:text-xl tL:w-60 tL:text-xl sL:w-64 sL:text-xl sL:-mt-4 mL:w-60 mL:text-xl lP:w-60 lP:text-xl lP:-mt-4"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="justify-center items-center place-content-center place-items-center">
              <button onClick={handleSubmit} className="w-40 h-12 bg-white cursor-pointer rounded-3xl border-2 border-[#9748FF] shadow-[inset_0px_-2px_0px_1px_#9748FF] group hover:bg-[#9748FF] transition duration-300 ease-in-out
                        smallP:mt-5 smallP:w-28 smallP:h-9 mP:mt-5 mP:w-40 mP:h-12 mP:text-base tP:mt-5">
                <span className="font-medium text-[#333] group-hover:text-white">Continue</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <button className="smallP:text-base smallP:mt-20 smallP:text-white mP:mt-24 mP:text-white mP:text-base tP:text-white tL:text-white sL:text-white mL:text-white lP:text-white">Continue as Friende</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import Main from './main';
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

I have tried to find information everywhere and trie it out but it doest work i even tried chatGpt, blackbox and Tabnin but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using `useNavigate` hook just `navigate("/main")` it will work

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
      const [inpty, setFull] = useState("");
      const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (inpty.trim().length === 0) {
          alert("Please input your name to continue");
        } else {
          navigate("/main")
        }
      }
```

Comment: I tried it and it dosent work

Comment: Post the error here you are getting in the console

Answer (score 0):

No offense, I understand that you're a newcomer, but you should really work on your grammar and question formatting. Most users will simply skip your question if it's gonna be in such poor state. Spell check tools and ChatGPT are free - use them.

I'd also recommend to learn [Markdown](https://www.markdownguide.org/getting-started/) to better format your posts and questions. For example, try to update your question like so:

```
Hello! I'm currently building a web page in React and I need to add
an `onClick` function to my button. This function should have
a simple `if-else` statement that, in the end, will open main.js.
However, I'm struggling to understand how React Router works.
Can someone help me with this?
```

As for the answer on you question. You lack understanding of how React functions. This will never work:

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (inpty.trim().length === 0) {
    alert("Please input your name to continue");
  } else {
    <Routes>
      <Link to={<Main/>}/>
    </Routes>
  }
}
```

It'll never work because in order to render a JSX element you need to return it as part of the `App` function result. If you want to display something by condition, you need to use `useState` or `useReducer` and filter elements using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator) or `if` statements:

```
function App() {
  // ...
  const [inpty, setFull] = useState("");
  // ...

  return (
    <>
      {inpty ? <YourLinkElement /> : null}
      <section>...</section>
    </>
  );
}
```

[The `Routes` component](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/routes) works in pair with `Route` components. This is kinda like `switch-case` statement, but using JSX components.

[The `to` attribute of the `Link`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link#state) component takes a string, not a JSX component.

There are many videos on YouTube on how React and its libraries work. Here is a pretty good one on [basics of ReactRouter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XN7E5tKM-no&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9iVKmtNuCeIswnQ97in2GGf&index=2).